# Heat map for a very large matrix, including NaNs

Tags: python, heatmap, large-data

I am trying to see if NaNs are concentrated somewhere, or if there is any pattern for their distribution.

The idea is to use python to plot a heatMap of the matrix (which is 200K rows and 1k columns) and set a special color for NaN values (the rest of the values can be represented by the same color, this doesn't matter)

An example of a possible display:
[image: A proposition for example]

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I think [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno) might be worth looking at. Not sure if it can do what you need, though...

Answer (score 2):

A *1:200* aspect ratio is pretty bad and, since you could run into memory issues, you should probably break it up into several *Nx1k* pieces.

That being said, here is my solution (inspired by your example image):

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

# generate random matrix
xDim = 2000
yDim = 4000
# number of nans
nNans = xDim*yDim*.1
rands = np.random.rand(yDim, xDim)

# create a skewed distribution for the nans
x = np.clip(np.random.gamma(2, yDim*.125, size=nNans).astype(np.int),0 ,yDim-1)
y = np.random.randint(0,xDim,size=nNans)
rands[x,y] = np.nan

# find the nans:
isNan = np.isnan(rands)

fig = plt.figure()

# make axesgrid so we can put a histogram-like plot next to the data
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 2), axes_pad=0.05)

# plot the data using binary colormap
grid[0].imshow(isNan, cmap=cm.binary)

# plot the histogram
grid[1].plot(np.sum(isNan,axis=1), range(isNan.shape[0]))

# set ticks and limits, so the figure looks nice
grid[0].set_xticks([0,250,500,750,1000,1250,1500,1750])
grid[1].set_xticks([0,250,500,750])
grid[1].set_xlim([0,750])
grid.axes_llc.set_ylim([0, yDim])
plt.show()
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Figure produced by the code]

Comment: Gosh, I realized only now that this question is almost half a year old... well, I hope the answer will still be useful for someone :D

Answer (score 0):

```
# Learn about API authentication here: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started
# Find your api_key here: https://plot.ly/settings/api

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [
    go.Heatmap(
        z=[[1, 20, 30],
        [20, 1, 60],
        [30, 60, 1]]
    )
]
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-heatm
```

soruce: https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/

Comment: thanks but no, I already know this simple solution and I want a way to plot a very large object (with NaNs) as explained in my post

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# create a matrix with random numbers
A = np.random.rand(2000,10)
# make some NaNs in it:
for _ in range(1000):
    i = np.random.randint(0,2000)
    j = np.random.randint(0,10)
    A[i,j] = np.nan
# get a matrix to plot with only the NaNs:
B = np.isnan(A)
# if NaN plot a point. 
for i in range(2000):
    for j in range(10):
        if B[i,j]: plt.scatter(i,j)
plt.show()
```

when using python 2.6 or 2.7 consider using xrange instead of range for speedup.

[image]

Note. it could be faster to do:

```
C = np.where(B)
plt.scatter(C[0],C[1])
```